# SSAS OLAP create a dimension with dynamic attributes

Tags: olap, olap-cube, ssas-2012

It is possible to create a dimension in a OLAP cube where the attibutes of this dimension are dynamic?

For instance, today I can have the attibutes A | B | C | D and tomorrow I can have the attibutes A | B | C | D | E.

Thanks in advance!